# How can I support min sdk 14 if my required lvl was 26?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-min-sdk

I need to develop an app which can support android version from 4.0 till latest. But as it was my first app I  started to develop it using android jetpack components and so on. My question is can use androidX support library to support older versions of devices or I have to make a new app from scratch? If I can migrate from min sdk 26 to 14 using androidX support lib, please help me with any examples.
Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

def room_version = "2.2.6"

compileOnly "com.squareup.inject:assisted-inject-annotations-dagger2:0.5.2"

kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.30.1-alpha"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02"
kapt 'com.squareup.inject:assisted-inject-processor-dagger2:0.5.2'

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'



implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"


implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"

def nav_version = "2.3.2"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.30.1-alpha"

implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"

implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlin_version}"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2"

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

And build script

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.3.2"
    ext.hilt_version = '2.28-alpha'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}